# css first-of-type and last-of-type

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` within css. Problem is `last-of-type` is not working. I have created this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/Womrva) from codepen.io.

```css
.col {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:300px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   margin-top:20px;
}

.you {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   padding:20px;
   background-color:black;
   border-radius:5px;
}

.me {
   float:right;
   width:100%;
   padding:20px;
   background-color:black;
}



.msg:first-of-type .you  {
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}

.msg:last-of-type .you {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}

.msg:first-of-type .me  {
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
}

.msg:last-of-type .me {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg"><div class="col you">a</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col you">a</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col you">a</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col you">a</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col me">s</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col me">s</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col me">s</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col me">s</div></div>
<div class="msg"><div class="col me">s</div></div>
```

Comment: You are looking for `first / last-of-class`...which **does not exist**.

Comment: @Paulie_D Are you sure that's what the OP is after? Even if there were a `:last-with-class`, that wouldn't solve the OP's problem, since all the parent divs are the same class. That is, In the OP's example, .msg:last-of-type is exactly the last div with class=msg.

Comment: So, I would have closed as "unclear what you're asking".